# c# find row index of specific numbers in a 2 dimensonal array

Tags: c#, matrix, indexing, duplicates

There's an input:

```
8 4 6 6 6 6 6 6
7 5 7 6 6 6 6 5
6 6 6 5 5 5 5 6
8 6 8 7 7 7 7 6
8 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
8 6 6 6 6 6 6 1
```

I have to find the greatest numbers in each column and get their row index, if there's multiple of the same greatest number in one column, I have to get all of their row indexes, and put them in an array, but if there's multiple of the same row index I just need one, and I have to put them in ascending order.

The first column's greatest number is 8, so the indexes from the first column are 0, 3, 4, 5.
The second colum's greatest number is 6, so the indexes from the second column are 2, 3, 4, 5 but I already have 3, 4, and 5 so I just need the 2
In the end I should have 0, 2, 3, 4, 5.

```
while (p < M)        //Getting the greatest numbers of each column
        {
            for (int l = 0; l < N; l++)
            {
                if (matrix[l, p] > max)
                {
                    max = matrix[l, p];
                }
            }
            greatestNum[p] = max;
            max = 0;
            p++;
        }
```

I just need help with getting the indexes and with the no duplicates thing. I can do the ascending order by myself. Every help is appreciated.

Comment: So in the end, if I understand you correctly, you only need **one** array that contains the indexes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HashSet<int>` to store unique rows:

```
using System.Linq;

...

private static int[] myIndexes(int[,] data) {
  // distinct rows which contain max values
  HashSet<int> result = new HashSet<int>();

  // for each column we find rows that contain max values 
  for (int c = 0; c < data.GetLength(1); ++c) {
    // max value so far
    int max = data[0, c];
    // List - we can have several rows with max value
    List<int> maxRows = new List<int>() {1}; 

    for (int r = 1; r < data.GetLength(0); ++r)
      if (data[r, c] == max)
        maxRows.Add(r + 1);
      else if (data[r, c] > max) {
        maxRows.Clear();
        max = data[r, c];
        maxRows.Add(r + 1);  
      } 
 
    foreach (int item in maxRows)
      result.Add(item);
  }

  // let's return ordered rows - OrderBy
  return result
    .OrderBy(row => row) 
    .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your help, seems to be working great. I forgot to mention that i need to add 1 to the indexes so they actually start from 1 and not 0. How could I do that?

Comment: @Gergő Szatmári: if you want 1 based rows you should add `1`s. I've edited the answer

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HashSet<T>` to store unique values of indexes.

`GreatestNumberIndexes` method finds maximums of current column and then adds the indexes of result HashSet. You can do `ToArray()` to get the indexes as an array too.

Here's the code:

```
private static HashSet<int> GreatestNumberIndexes(int[,] matrix,
    int rows, int cols)
{
    var indexes = new HashSet<int>();
    for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        var max = int.MinValue;
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
            if (matrix[j, i] > max)
                max = matrix[j, i];

        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
            if (matrix[j, i] == max)
                indexes.Add(j);
    }

    return indexes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution but:

```
int[,] matrix = new int[,]
{
    {8, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6},
    {7, 5, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5},
    {6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6},
    {8, 6, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6},
    {8, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6},
    {8, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1}
};

HashSet<int> indicesOfMaxNumbers = new HashSet<int>();
for (int col = 0; col < matrix.GetLength(1); col++)
{
    int curMax = matrix[0, col];
    for (int row = 1; row < matrix.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        if (curMax <= matrix[row, col])
        {
            curMax = matrix[row, col];
        }
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        if (curMax == matrix[row, col])
        {
            indicesOfMaxNumbers.Add(row + 1);
        }
    }


}
indicesOfMaxNumbers.Sort();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", indicesOfMaxNumbers));
```

I find the greatest element in each column and then I insert the index if it is not already been inserted.

P.S. you can play with it a bit to optimize it as I am 100% sure there is a better solution

Comment: Hey, thanks for your solution, how could I add 1 to the indices so they start from 1 and not 0?

Comment: You can add the row+1 I have edited the answer

Comment: `curMax < matrix[row, col]`. This is esentially the same as ndogac's answer, and was posted 6 minutes later..

Comment: That is right. But I am not sure what is your point.

Answer (score 0):

The LINQ method `.Distinct()` removes all duplicate values of an `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
// init your example of rows
var matrixXY = new List<List<int>>
{
    new List<int>{8, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6},
    new List<int>{7, 5, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5},
    new List<int>{6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6},
    new List<int>{8, 6, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6},
    new List<int>{8, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6},
    new List<int>{8, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1}
};

// turn it around for easier management
var matrixYX = new List<List<int>>();
for (int y = 0; y < matrixXY[0].Count; y++)
{
    matrixYX.Add(new List<int>());
    for (int x = 0; x < matrixXY.Count; x++)
    {
        matrixYX[y].Add(matrixXY[x][y]);
    }
}

// get index of each max number per column
var indexGroups = matrixYX.Select(values =>
{
    var maxValue = values.Max();
    return values
        .Select((value, i) => (Value: value, Index: i + 1))
        .Where(tuple => tuple.Value == maxValue)
        .Select(tuple => tuple.Index);
});

// pass all indexes into one array
var result = indexGroups
    .SelectMany(indexes => indexes)
    .Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Because there's always someone that posts a LINQ answer for these things..</sup>

```
matrix.Cast<int>() 
  .Select((v, i) => new { R = i/matrix.GetLength(1), C = i%matrix.GetLength(1), V = v })
  .GroupBy(rcv => rcv.C, rcv => rcv, (k, g) => g.OrderByDescending(rcv => rcv.V)) 
  .SelectMany(g => g.TakeWhile(rcv => rcv.V == g.First().V), (g, rcv) => rcv.R)
  .Distinct()
```

#### Foreword

Let's go through it, for the learning experience. I'm not sure I'd use this in prod but it's interesting as a thought exercise and I present it here for learning and curiosity.

**You would be the judge of whether you understand it at a glance**; if you and the others on your team *would* understand it *and* it tested to be more preformant than a non-LINQ solution (which I doubt it would), then great..

..but please avoid using code that's "trick" yet needs a document comment going with it for anyone to understand it.

For the avoidance of doubt, I'm posting this answer because it's an alternative to the other very similar answers and it presents a great education opportunity for some of the less often used aspects of LINQ hence I think you'll learn something from it, but I genuinely think you should actually use ndogac's answer in your production system..

#### The Blahblah

A useful facet of N dimensional arrays is that you can enumerate them as though they're a single dimension. In the case of this 2D one, if you were to enumerate it, you'd get all the items from the first row, then all the items of the second:

```
foreach(int n in matrix) ....

8 4 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 5 7 6 6 6 6 5 6 6 6 5 5 5 5 6 8 6 8 7 7 7 7 6 8 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 8 6 6 6 6 6 6 1
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
first row       second row
```

Now, 2D arrays don't implement `IEnumerable<T>` so we can't straight call `.Select` style LINQ extensions on them but you can get the same effect with the `Cast<T>` operator, which effectively does a `foreach(int v in array) yield return v;` in this case, so it gives us a single enumerable stream of `int`s to work with.

We want to work with them by column.

We can calculate the column and the row by using the `Select` method that gives us the index of the item as well as the item:

```
.Select((v, i) => new { R = i/matrix.GetLength(1), C = i%matrix.GetLength(1), V = v })
```

`v` is the item, `i` is the index it's found at. The row `R` is given by the index divided by the row length: from indexes 0 to 7, all divided by 8, is 0. From indexes 8 thru 15, dividd by 8, is 1 etc. The column `C` is given by the modulo aka the remainder of the division above

This outputs an anonymous type with R C and V properties giving the Row, Column and Value appropriately. This is fed into...

```
.GroupBy(rcv => rcv.C, (k, g) => g.OrderByDescending(rcv => rcv.V))
```

This form of GroupBy is less often used, and as presented here is notionally the equivalent of:

```
.GroupBy(rcv => rcv.C)
.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(rcv => rcv.V))
```

Which will group by the column, because we want to divide the stream into a "list of lists" where all values with the same column are comparable so we can find the Max of the value *in the column*.

There are a few strategies we could use to get row indexes of the maxes, for example:

- find the max then find all those where the value is the max,
- order by value descending and take while the value is the same as the first

This solution uses the second, just because TakeWhile isn't often used and this is an academic exercise. In this premilinary step we sort the column so the max values are near the top. Remember that we do know the row indexes in R, so it doesn't matter that we sort the rows out of original order

```
.SelectMany(g => g.TakeWhile(rcv => rcv.V == g.First().V), (g, rcv) => rcv.R)
```

SelectMany is another less-often-used construct and this form perhaps more so. The second argument is, again, just a short form of:

```
.SelectMany(g => g.TakeWhile(rcv => rcv.V == g.First().V))
.Select(rcv => rcv.R)
```

SelectMany is an ungrouping operation: it takes our 8 lists of 6 object per list that GroupBy gave us and unpacks it to upto-48 objects again..

SelectMany expects to be given a collection as its first argument, and here we give it a reduction of the 6 items in the column: we're going to `TakeWhile` the number is the same as the first number. It's a little inefficient here to calculate the first over and over again, but it's more efficient than calculating the Max over and over again. You could say `g => { var f = g.First().V; return g.TakeWhile(rcv => rcv.V == f) ]` to calculate the first only once

So the output from the group was an ordered list of 6 RCVs, descending oprder of V, and that became our "group" `g`. Then we reduced it to just those that were the same V as the first V (which must be the max by definition of Order By Descending) meaning we get 4 RCVs out of the first column (those with a V of 8)

SelectMany will visit each column, get the max RCVs from every group and emit them according to the second argument `(g, rcv) => rcv.R` , which pulls just the row index R, and adds 1 to it (your subsequent requirement in other comments)

The end result of this is a stream of row indexes that have duplicates in, so we use `Distinct()` to remove them

---

Footnote, if you wanted something that worked by "where Value is equal to Max Value" it might look like:

```
matrix.Cast<int>() 
  .Select((v, i) => new { R = i/matrix.GetLength(1), C = i%matrix.GetLength(1), V = v })
  .GroupBy(rcv => rcv.C, (g, rcv) => new { G = g, M = g.Max(rcv => rcv.V) }) 
  .SelectMany(gwm => gwm.G.Where(rcv => rcv.V == gwm.M), (g, rcv) => rcv.R + 1))
  .Distinct()
```

In brief the GroupBy outputs a new anonymous type that includes both the group (the column of values) and the Max of those. The SelectMany will rely on the max so we don't want to calculate it over and over again). The GroupBy produces a "group with max" that I aliased to `gwm` in the SelectMany. The SelectMany, does a `Where` for only those with the max value..

..but other than that it's the same as before